# Dynamically Center Div Content by Screen Position

Tags: dynamic, coffeescript

I am trying to center the contents of a Div when the user has scrolled down passed the header which is always at the top and is always 120px high. I am wanting to use vanilla javascript and have not found a way to do this?

I need to also be able to decide what is centered and what is not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Again, No jquery please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this.

```
var sections = $('.section');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    sections.removeClass('selected').each(function() {
        var top = $(this).offset().top,
            bottom = top + $(this).height();
        if (currentPosition >= top && currentPosition <= bottom) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

Select could do text align center or something.